# Which penalization works for this optimisation problem?

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization

Let $m,n$ be given integers. Set $K:=[0,1]^{mn}$ and define the function  $L:K\times\mathbb R_+^m\times\mathbb R_+^n\to\mathbb R$ as follows : for $z=(z_{i,j})\in K$, $a=(a_i)\in\mathbb R_+^m$, $b=(b_j)\in\mathbb R_+^n$,

$$L(z,a,b):=\sum_{1\le i\le m, 1\le j\le n}
\gamma_{i,j}\left[ a_i b_j \left( ( 1 - z_{i,j}) p_{i,j} + h_{i,j} \right) \right],$$

where $\gamma_{i,j}>0$, $p_{i,j}\ge 0$, $h_{i,j}$ are fixed parameters. Let $C\subset \mathbb R_+^m\times\mathbb R_+^n$ be the subset of elements $(a,b)$ satisfying

$$
\alpha_i = a_i \sum_{1\le j\le n}\gamma_{i,j} b_j \quad\mbox{and} \quad \beta_j = b_j \sum_{1\le i\le m}\gamma_{i,j} a_i 
$$

for all $1\le i\le m$ and $1\le j\le n$, where $\alpha_1,\ldots, \alpha_m, \beta_1,\ldots, \beta_n \in (0,1)$ are such that

$$\sum_{1\le i\le m}\alpha_i = 1 = \sum_{1\le j\le n}\beta_j.$$

Now consider some "penalization function" $P:K\times\mathbb R_+^m\times\mathbb R_+^n\to\mathbb R_+$. My question is when it holds

$$\lim_{N\to\infty} \left(\inf_{(z,a,b)\in K\times\mathbb R_+^m\times\mathbb R_+^n} (L+NP)(z,a,b)\right) = \inf_{(z,a,b)\in K\times C}L(z,a,b)? $$

A natural attempt is

$$P(z,a,b):= \sum_{1\le i\le m}\big(a_i \sum_{1\le j\le n}\gamma_{i,j} b_j  -\alpha_i\big)^2+ \sum_{1\le j\le n}\big(b_j \sum_{1\le i\le m}\gamma_{i,j} a_i -\beta_j\big)^2.$$

Can we expect the above convergence for this choice?